# what is the difference between new int() and new int[]

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

```
int main()
{
  int *y = new int(5);
  cout << "y = " << y << " &y = " << &y << " *y = " << *y << endl;
  int *p = new int[5];
  cout << "p = " << p << " &p = " << &p << " *p =" << *p << endl;
}
```

one used [] and another one used (), what's the different and how it works? Can someone help to explain to me? Thanks!

Comment: What does your C++ book say about this?

Comment: Thanks!! That help me a lot. The int *y = new int(5) mean that the value 5 is given to *y. But int[5] mean that make a 5 int numbers spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You output so many things in your `std::cout` but most of them don't matter.

try

```
std::cout << sizeof(int(5)) << " " << sizeof(int[5]) << "\n";
```

which will output

```
4 20
```

since `int(5)` means a single integer initialised with 5. So `sizeof` yields the size of an `int`.

On the other hand, `int[5]` is what you expect: an array of 5 integers, so `sizeof` yields `5*sizeof(int)`.

Two more remarks:

- creating good old arrays with `new` definitely is something a beginner should refrain from. If you need dynamically sized indexable storage, use `std::vector`.  There is no speed panalty.
- refrain from `using namespace std;` simply type the `std::`, that makes the code more readable and clearly separates your stuff from library stuff.

Comment: Help me to deeper understand!

Comment: "*there is no speed penalty*" - not true. Speed is *slightly* slower with a `std::vector`. `new int[5]` allocates memory but does not fill it. `vector<int>(5)` (or `vector.resize(5)`) allocates memory and zero-initializes it. Also, `operator[]` on a raw pointer is just a simple dereference of the pointer plus an offset, whereas `operator[]` on a `std::vector` is a function call that has to manipulate the call stack. Speed differences are negligible, but they do exist.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The compiler will inline the call to the operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *y = new int(5)
```

This allocates a single `int` and sets its value to 5, then assigns `y` to point at the allocated `int`.

```
int *p = new int[5]
```

This allocates an array of 5 `int`s, whose values are initially undefined, then assigns `p` to point at the first `int` in the allocated array.

Comment: Is it correct/appropriate to say on `new int(5)` there is a call to int constructor and the result of that goes as an argument to operator new? And on `new int[5]` we are allocating an int array and the result of that goes to operator new?

Comment: @KcFnMi No to both. Fundamental types like `int` don't have constructors, `int(5)` is simply [direct-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). But in any case, a [`new-expression`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) does not construct an object and then pass it to [`operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). The opposite happens - the `new-expression` calls `operator new` first to allocate memory for the size of the object/array, and then creates the object/array inside of that memory.

Comment: We call "new-expression" the part that starts with new keyword, i.e. `new int(5);`? And we say `int(5)` is the argument passed to operator new?

Comment: @KcFnMi `new-expression` and `operator new` are two separate and distinct things in C++.  The entire `new int(5)` is a `new-expression`. The compiler translates it into two distinct actions - a call to `operator new` to allocate memory for an `int`, and then initialize that `int` with the value `5`. For example, it's equivalent to (not exactly, but for demonstration purposes): `int* i = (int*) ::operator new(sizeof(int)); *i = 5;`